# Silverlight - Strategy passing Data to a User Control

Tags: silverlight

Silverlight5

From a button click on Tab1Data I want to pass a parameter to Tab2_1Data

Am currently doing it with a global public property(!) on the MainPage which each UserControl can reference using this [helper](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx)

Is there a better way using a non MVVM approach to pass parameters?

```
 <controls:TabControl Name="TabOverallMain">
                        <!-- Tab 1 -->
                        <controls:TabItem Header="Home Screen" IsSelected="True">
                            <UserControls:Tab1Data />
                        </controls:TabItem>

                        <!-- Tab 2 -->
                        <controls:TabItem Header="Admin">
                            <Grid>
                                <controls:TabControl>
                                    <!-- Tab 2_1 -->
                                    <controls:TabItem Header="Users">
                                        <UserControls:Tab2_1Data />
                                    </controls:TabItem>
```

EDIT:
Using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42203/How-to-Implement-a-DependencyProperty) I implemented a DependencyProperty in my Tab2_1Data control:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty CaptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Caption", typeof(string), typeof(WidgetControl),null);

        public string Caption
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CaptionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CaptionProperty, value); }
        }
```

which I then referenced from my Tab1Data user control by:

```
wid.Caption = "hello world";
```

This is fine for me now.. although databinding between the 2 looks v.good too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you dont want to use MVVM, try use data binding.. You will need to expose the parameter as a dependency propety int the first control

Here's some pseudo code. Create a dependency property on Tab1Data called MyParam

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyParamProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyParam",
                int, typeof(Tab2_1Data), null);

public int MyParam
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MyParamProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MyParamProperty, value);
    }
}

<controls:TabItem Header="Home Screen" IsSelected="True">
    <UserControls:Tab1Data x:Name="OneCtrl"  />
</controls:TabItem>
```

Then create a dependency property (similar to above) on the second control called something like ParamFromControlOne... then bind them

```
<UserControls:Tab2_1Data ParamFromControlOne="{Binding MyParam, ElementName=OneCtrl}" />
```

That's not tested and thrown together using Notepad, but that is the path I would go down

Comment: Thanks tsiorn! See Edit in main question for code that I implemented.